# Regular Expression to format certain lines of text

Tags: php, regex, formatting

I am trying to improve my in-site personal messaging system by making it look nicer and feel more like e-mail.  I currently add > before each line of replied text, but I would also like to add formatting such as font color to lines that start with ">" without the quotes.  I am not sure how I would close the lines out with a regular expression.  To open it I assume I should do something like the following?

```
$new_text = preg_replace("\> \is", "<font color=\"grey\">> ", $text);
```

Comment: Could you give us some more information?  What language you are using to run your PM system, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_replace("/^(>.*)$/im", "<span style=\"color: red;\">\\1</span>", $reply);
```

Comment: This works, but had one small error, fixed below:

preg_replace("/^(>.*)$/im", "<span style=\"color: red;\n\">\\1</span>", $reply);

Comment: That regexp looks wrong, it would match the whole variable as long as it started with a ">"....

Might as well use echo "<span style=\"color: red;\">".$reply."</span>"

Comment: @Dougle - It matches each line in a multiline $reply that starts with a > and replaces it with the match, wrapped in a span.  It does work correctly, as the OP mentioned.  Give it a try to prove it to yourself.

Comment: @Dougle - I see why you are confused now.  The `/im` at the end of the expression is the key.  The `m` changes the meaning of `^` and `$`.  See http://us.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php for details.

Comment: Ah my bad, apologies i didn't see the m flag

Answer (score 0):

```
ereg_replace('^>(.*)', '<span class="quoted">&gt;\\1</span>', $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/(\n>[^\n]*)+/','<span class="reply">$1</span>', $message);
```

Something like that will enclose the quoted reply with something you can style up.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the good answers already posted, you may want to escape the captured text before treating it as HTML.  With simple replacement, some characters in the quoted text (specifically '<', '>' and '&') will make your generated HTML invalid.  (I'm assuming it isn't already escaped, or you would need to match ">" instead of ">".)

To ensure that the replacement yields valid HTML, you can do something like this:

```
function quote_markup($matches) {
    $quote = htmlspecialchars($matches[1]);
    return "<span style=\"color: red;\">$quote</span>",
}

preg_replace_callback("/^(>.*)$/im", 'quote_markup', $reply);
```